# Любой, каждый, все

Tags: значение-слов

"Любой", "каждый" - это синонимы?
Это то же ли самое: "Любой может выиграть в лотерею", "Каждый может выиграть в лотерею", "Все могут выиграть в лотерею"? А тут: "Любой может стать Президентом", "Каждый может стать стать Президентом", "Все могут стать Президентом"? Президент у нас один, все им стать не могут. А каждый или любой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Действительно, в естественном языке (в отличие от математики), значения "любой" и "каждый" не являются строго формализуемыми, часто понимание субъективно, особенно это проявляется у "каждый". Оно может означать и "любой" и "все" - в зависимости от контекста. В целом бы ответил так. "Любой" и "каждый" - синонимы близкие, но не полные. Различие как раз и проявляется на подобных примерах.

Субъективно я это понимаю так.
***Каждый может выиграть в лотерею", "Все могут выиграть в лотерею"*** - это синонимичные утверждения. И оба, таким образом, ложны.
***"Любой может выиграть в лотерею"*** - а это уже другой смысл, утверждение истинно, любой (участвующий) может выиграть. Любой, но не каждый, то есть "не все". "Любой" здесь означает примерно *"случайным образом выбранный"* и поэтом совсем не "каждый" и не "все". Поэтому рекламные слоганы организаторов лотереи обычно лукавы.

А во второй группе ситуация иная.

***"Любой может стать Президентом"="Каждый может стать стать Президентом"*** - это истинно (ну теоретически: может каждый гражданин, кому это позволяет Конституция). "Любой" здесь равно "каждый". Можно спорить, но в отношении именно этой возможности ("стать президентом") я это так воспринимаю. ***"Все могут стать Президентом"*** - ну а тут понятно, что совсем другой смысл, 
"Любой" и "каждый" оба означает предопределенный выбор, поэтому значения сближаются.

Да, всё очень условно, кому-то может показаться, что всё наоборот. Но ваш-то вопрос о том, одинаковы ли значения. И даже этот кто-то подтвердит, что значения для него разные. Если, конечно, этот кто-то не окажется махровым Айтишником или математиком, которому все кошки серы. Потому, что в математике, как я уже сказал, эти слова полностью синонимичны, хотя и там есть тонкости употребления, но не значения.

Comment: Г-н @Morkovkin, вы опять превзошли себя. На троллевский вопрос такой "научный" ответ. И ведь на полном серьёзе! Прямо восхищаюсь.  P.S. Да, минус уж не ставлю, ибо истинное удовольствие доставили.

Answer (score 1):

Любой и каждый синонимы, но они отличаются оттенком значения.

Местоимению **каждый** присуще особое значение **«один из всех в данном количественном ряду», «любой из себе подобных, взятый отдельно»**, ***например: зачетная книжка выдается каждому студенту; ср. также: на каждом шагу, каждый третий день, каждые два часа.***

Слово **любой** имеет особое значение **«какой угодно на выбор»,** например: **выбирайте любую книгу, справиться в любом почтовом отделении, перенести заседание на любой другой день.**

См.: [Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Answer (score 0):

**Кто и что может (каждый, любой, всякий, все)**

**1) Лотерея**

Круг лиц ограничен людьми, купившими билет. Если это честная лотерея, то **каждый, любой и всякий** может в нее выиграть. **Все, как правило, не могут**, так как количество призов ограничено. Исключение составляет беспроигрышная лотерея, в которую выигрывают все, купившие билет.

**2) Президент**

Согласно ст. 81 п. 2 главы 4 Конституции РФ, формально президентом Российской Федерации может стать **гражданин России,** достигший 35-летнего возраста и проживающий на территории страны не менее 10 лет.  Такие показатели, как пол, национальность, образование, род деятельности, материальное положение, политические убеждения и религиозная принадлежность значения не имеют. Исходя из этого, создается впечатление, что президентом Российской Федерации может быть избран практически **каждый из нас**.

Однако реальный порядок выборов главы государства определяется Федеральным законом РФ от 10 января 2003 г. N 19-ФЗ «О выборах президента Российской Федерации». Читать дальше.. [Кто может быть президентом РФ | 36on.ru](http://36on.ru/business/power/7538-kto-mozhet-byt-prezidentom-rf)

Таким образом, круг лиц, которые могут стать президентом, существенно ограничен: **это люди, которых допустят до выборов.**

Поэтому **только условно можно сказать, что президентом у нас может стать любой, каждый и всякий**. В действительности рассматриваются только кандидаты в президенты, **а дальше всё как в лотерее, только приз всего один.** Соответственно,  все президентом стать не могут.

**Из словаря:**

**КАЖДЫЙ**,  Один из ряда подобных, взятый подряд, без выбора, без пропусков; **всякий, любой**. м.; Каждая, -ой; ж. **Всякий человек**.

**ЛЮБОЙ**, 1. Всякий, каждый.  2. Какой угодно (на выбор). II. местоим. сущ. 1. только м.: любой,  **Всякий, каждый** человек; какой угодно человек.

**ВСЕ**,  II. местоим. сущ. Те, кто (что) есть, **в полном составе, без исключения.** Все в семье любят спорт. Все меня гонят. Для всех я чужой. Он всем надоел! Пойду вместе со всеми. Поздравили всех: от мала до велика.

Comment: *президентом Российской Федерации может быть избран практически каждый из нас* - вы здесь противопоставляете "каждый" "любому"? (Дальнейшие пояснения про ФЗ - это уже не в тему, имхо).

Comment: Это просто цитата, я ничего не противопоставляю. Любой, каждый, всякий  (из какой-то группы) выступают как синонимы, что видно из словаря.  Все -  это вся группа полностью, без исключения.  Материал  про ФЗ привожу для справок, чтобы показать, что суждение должно быть практически верным, а не отвлеченно-условным.

Comment: *Исходя из этого, создается впечатление, что президентом Российской Федерации может быть избран практически каждый из нас.*  - Это цитата?! Откуда?

Comment: Из Интернета, адрес указан. Каждый из нас  - это любой гражданин РФ, то есть мы - это определенная группа,  граждане РФ, но в действительности эта группа весьма невелика. Мне кажется, этот вопрос из области софистики (софисты с помощью особых приемов могли защищать или опровергать любые мнения).  Насколько я помню,  для них было важно  в цепочке рассуждений убедить человека в ложном суждении, которое на вид кажется верным. Поэтому надо тщательно проверять каждое звено. К примеру, "все могут выиграть в лотерею"  - это суждение обычно неверно, хотя на слух вполне приемлемо.

Comment: Ну в Интернете можно чего угодно найти. Я решил, что это что-то авторитетное. Ладно, спасибо за разъяснения. Тем не менее основной вопрос в силе. Вы в этой фразе-цитату видите противопоставление "каждого" "любому"? Иначе вообще непонятно, к чему она тут.